My Flutter App is stuck on the splash screen(Flutter Logo) Android
I was writing some code. Restarted the app and now I am stuck on the flutter splash screen.
The Problem
**Tried using flutter -v didnt help. Everything seems correct...
**
I tried flutter -clean the problem persists
I am using a pixel 8 pro android emulator on windows using VScode
I tried to restart the app, Expected it to work. But resulted in being stuck on the flutter logo.
I tried creating a new app works as expected
Here is my main.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:expense_tracker/widgets/expenses.dart';

var kColorScheme =
    ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 96, 59, 181));
var kDarkColorScheme = ColorScheme.fromSeed(
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
    seedColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 5, 99, 125));
void main() {
  (fn) {
    runApp(
      MaterialApp(
        darkTheme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
          colorScheme: kDarkColorScheme,
          cardTheme: const CardTheme().copyWith(
            color: kDarkColorScheme.secondaryContainer,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 16,
              vertical: 8,
            ),
          ),
          elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                backgroundColor: kDarkColorScheme.primaryContainer,
                foregroundColor: kDarkColorScheme.onPrimaryContainer),
          ),
        ),
        theme: ThemeData().copyWith(
          colorScheme: kColorScheme,
          appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme().copyWith(
            backgroundColor: kColorScheme.onPrimaryContainer,
            foregroundColor: kColorScheme.primaryContainer,
          ),
          elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              backgroundColor: kColorScheme.primaryContainer,
            ),
          ),
          cardTheme: const CardTheme().copyWith(
            color: kColorScheme.secondaryContainer,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 16,
              vertical: 8,
            ),
          ),
          textTheme: ThemeData().textTheme.copyWith(
                titleLarge: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: kColorScheme.onSecondaryContainer,
                    fontSize: 16),
              ),
        ),
        home: const Expenses(),
      ),
    );
  };
}



You're not calling runApp. The runApp is defined inside a callback, which I'm not sure why you need to do that?

@DhafinRayhan Removing that fixed it. I forgot to comment that out
